# Google Chrome not showing Ajax Calls on Inspect Element

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome Version: 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)
I always could be able to see/teste my ajax calls using this feature, now I can't see any ajax call anymore.

Code:

#### Ajax Call

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        $('#btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:  'teste.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {teste: 1 },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### Teste.php

```
<?php 
include 'conexao.php';

    echo '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@SDADSADSADD@@@';
    $pdo = Conectar();  
   $query = $pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO user(nome, email) VALUES (:nome, :email)" );
   $query->bindValue(":nome", "Alan");
   $query->bindValue(":email", "Alan@gmail");
   $query->execute();   
 ?>
```

#### Inspect Element

After the click
[image]

Comment: did you click the `#btn` ?

Comment: Ya, thats the screenshot after the click. I can persist into database but I can't see the `echos` from `teste.php` file. That's why I wanted to check it in NETWORK